# Does a relational database schema have to be normalized to 3rd normal form in order for it to be ORM-mappable?

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

[Jooq](https://www.jooq.org/) claims that there is no impedance mismatch when it comes to relational database schemas and object-oriented modelling of the data.

So, given a database schema that is asking to be wrapped in an application layer, does the DB schema have to be normalized to 3rd normal form in order for there to be optimal mapping between the DB schema, the ORM layer and the application?

Comment: A DB schema should always be normalized, no matter what.

Comment: Depends on your ORM, some have modes for dealing with "legacy schema" systems, but generally normalized data is more friendly to most of them.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably referring to this [jOOQ blog post here](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/08/26/there-is-no-such-thing-as-object-relational-impedance-mismatch/), which is a bit academic, not necessarily practical. It essentially says that what people call "impedance mismatch" may be caused by a lack of ORM features, not by the concept of ORMs per se.

This discussion has nothing to do with normalisation. As far as mapping is concerned, you can always map any table model to any object model if you correctly apply mapping rules and if you manually handle all the disadvantages of denormalisation (e.g. preventing inconsistencies in duplicate data). Having said so: the advantages of normalisation *will* make your life easier on all layers.

Note: if your schema is not normalised, chances are that it might have been designed for an analytic workload, not a transactional one, in case of which using an ORM might be overkill. [Using a SQL based API like JDBC, jOOQ, etc. might be the better choice](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/03/24/jooq-vs-hibernate-when-to-choose-which/)